# How to obtain all executed sql statements and execution time in jpa through aop or interceptor,

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop, aspect

Now I am using cat3 for tracking monitoring. I need to track the springboot using jpa and count the execution statements and duration of sql. I have not found a suitable entrance implementation. Do you have any good methods?

I tried using aspect to intercept jpa's execution sql entry, but it never took effect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you. 